Blazor WebAssembly SSR JWT Tokens Authentication on server side rendering
I want to use jwt tokens auth scheme in my blazor app with global auto interactivity. Content of page is dependant on current auth state and I want to render something else when user is authorized. My problem referes to first render of page on server. How can I determine if user who made request is authorized? I feel like I have to use cookie authorization to store auth token and also send it with refresh page request.
Flow would be following:

User performs login request through httpClient which sends login and password to server
Server returns user's jwt token
Client app saves it to local sorage and also sets cookie which will be sent to server on page reload

Normally api requests would be authorized through authorization header passed to http client from local storage but when page is refreshed server will recive cookie containing jwt token and based on that authorization will be performed to render according ui.
I know i can use some kind of placeholder for first server render and then adjust ui on client side but i don't like this solution.
Another solution would be to use only cookie auth and pass state of auth from serwer to interactive components but as far as i know that requires page reload after login request and i want to avoid that.
Taking into account signalR rendering before web assembly is ready porobably could also adds complexity to this solution so i'm wondering if it is good approach or maybe I can use some simpler solution to achieve what i want?

Look at what they are doing with the PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider in the individual accounts template particularly its use of the  PersistentComponentState class to transfer the identity to the client for the attributes to work.

yes, I looked into that template but as I mentioned in question I don't want to do it like that becouse all pages related to login are staticly rendered and requires page reload on login.

You could use the PersistentComponentState for your own provider... I use it to safely send configs to the client on startup without having to use an appsettings accessible to the browser. The components I use to do this render nothing.
